# Xcode 15.1 - Project Crashes and Compilation Error after Update

Tags: ios, xcode, crash, xcode15

I recently updated my Xcode project from Ventura 13 to Sonoma 14, and further to Xcode 15.1. However, I am encountering severe issues, and I'm seeking help to resolve them. Here are the problems I'm facing:

**Xcode Crashes:**

Whenever I open a Swift file or encounter an error, Xcode crashes with the message "Xcode quit unexpectedly." I've checked the system logs, but I'm struggling to pinpoint the cause of the crash.

**Compilation Error:**

When attempting to run the project, I receive a compilation error: "command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code Xcode." **This was not an issue in the previous versions (Ventura 13 and Sonoma 14)**

Steps I've Tried:

- Reinstalling Xcode
- Updating Pods
- Cleaning Project
- Cleaning Build Folder

Expectations:
I anticipated that these steps would resolve the Xcode crashing and compilation error issues. Unfortunately, despite my efforts, the problems persist, and I haven't been able to identify a solution.